# Postman: How can validate a key in JSON response

Tags: javascript, postman

I need to validate the next 2 keys: `key1` and `key2`:

```
{
 "data": [
    {
        "id": "123",
        "type": "something",
        "created": "1540952074",
        "test": [
            {
                "key1": "asd123",
                "key2": "166802"
            }
        ]
    },
```

I'm only interested in validate that those keys already exist.

I did this test:

```
pm.test('returns the correct parameters by type', () => {
  for (i = 0; i < jsonData.data.length; i++) {
    if (jsonData.data[i].type === 'something') {
      // for (j = 0; j < jsonData.data.test.length; j++) {

      pm.expect(jsonData.data[i]).to.have.property('id');
      pm.expect(jsonData.data[i]).to.have.property('type');
      pm.expect(jsonData.data[i]).to.have.property('created');

      pm.expect(jsonData.data[i].test[0]).to.have.property('key1');
      pm.expect(jsonData.data[i].test[0]).to.have.property('key2');
    }
  }
});
```

that returns the following error:

```
returns the correct parameters by type | TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

but if I put a console.log with `jsonData.data[i].test[0]`, the console show me the 2 parameters into an object correctly:

```
Object:{}
key1:"asd123"
key2:"166802"
```

Any idea how can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: What does this have to do with Postman?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't really see the full response data but this might work for you:

```
let jsonData = {
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "123",
            "type": "something",
            "created": "1540952074",
            "test": [
                {
                    "key1": "asd123",
                    "key2": "166802"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

pm.test("My Test", () => {
    _.each(jsonData.data, (item) => {
        if(item.type === "something") {
            pm.expect(_.first(item.test)).to.have.keys('key1', 'key2')
        }
    })
})
```

As that's just an example of a test using the data from the `jsonData` object above it, this will not work for your response data.

You could try this?

```
pm.test("My Test", () => {
    _.each(pm.response.json().data, (data) => {
        if(data.type === "something") {
            _.each(data.test, (test) => {
              pm.expect(test).to.have.keys('key1', 'key2')  
            })
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer!, but is not working. I've received this error:
'returns the correct parameters by type | TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object'
any idea?

Comment: What's the except response that you're getting? This was just an example and It wouldn't do anything with your response data as it is. Updated my answer.

Comment: data contains another object with the same structure. Let me put a portion of code example below.

    {
    "data": [
    {
        "id": "123",
        "type": "something",
        "created": "1540952074",
        "test": [
            {
                "key1": "asd123",
                "key2": "166802"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
            "id": "123",
            "type": "something",
            "created": "1540952074",
   }
 }

Comment: Update the question, don't add it to a comment. It makes it horrible to read :)

Comment: Updated my answer